# Is media still displayed in 4k with a scaled resolution on an external 4k display?

Tags: display, resolution

I'm currently using a 4k display with my MBP. I scaled it a little since 4k is quite small on 27 ".

However, I don't really find information on whether scaling means real scaling or just using another resolution. Or to put it differently, when watching, let's say, a video in 4k, will it be 4k or in a different resolution fitting the "scaling"?

[image: screenshot of display settings]

Comment: It **may** depend on whether you see the Display prefs in that "Larger Text" type of format. I had a similar question recently & as my screen doesn't show that type of setting, my conclusion was that set to 1080p, that's all I got. - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391655/4k-movie-on-4k-screen-scaled-to-1080 There's a deleted earlier answer [you won't unfortunately be able to see] that maybe hinted towards that, but no actual confirmation.

Comment: @Tetsujin I added a screenshot. The settings for "larger text" are there.

Comment: I get the 4k option, but then, it doesn't really prove anything, since the scaled resolution is between 2k and 4k. So, YouTube would pretty much still provide you with the 4k option. :D

Comment: Try the same test as I did - see if you can play a YouTube 4k video. I didn't get the option, it stopped at 1080. I also tested a downloaded 4k demo, but tbh it was hard to tell the difference. I've ended up just being happy at 1080. [sorry, typo in last version]

Comment: tbh, I ended up thinking, if I can't tell the difference, what does it matter ;-)